# How to print out an odd integers in R?

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:10) print(i)
for (i in 1:10) if .... ??
```

what is the right expression to specify an odd numbers ?

Comment: x=seq(1,10,by=2)
 x
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

Comment: Worth linking to this pretty-good wiki entry for dealing with homework questions, which this looks to be. @Anhar, please note that it is OK to ask homework questions on SO, with certain caveats. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812

Comment: Try initializing a counter, `i <- 0`, and then creating a `repeat` loop in which `i` is incremented, and calls to `print(i)` and `break` are made when appropriate. Look up documentation for a function, like `repeat`, by typing `?repeat` at the console.

Comment: You may wish to change your question to demonstrate research effort. Here's an article from the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, you could explain the requirements of the question (and the fact that it is for homework) in the body of the question, not just its title.

Comment: @Frank - `?"repeat"` that will have to be - using `?repeat` will just sit there waiting for input

Answer (score 3):

One possibility if for some reason you **must** avoid using `seq()`

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  if (i %% 2 ==1) print(i)
}

#[1] 1
#[1] 3
#[1] 5
#[1] 7
#[1] 9
```